# Accounting for gravity when shooting an arrow at a coordinate

Tags: java, android, math, physics, projectile

So I am making a 2D android game where you aim with your cursor and your character shoots where your cursor clicks.
When the arrow is created this method is called

```
private final float GRAVITY = 100, SPEED = 50f;

public Arrow(float dx, float dy, float x1, float y1, float x2, float y2,)
{
    destination = new Vector2(dx, dy);//mouse clicked here

    //x1 and y1 are the starting coordinates
    bounds = new Polyline(new float[]{x1, y1, x2, y2});

    double r = Math.atan2(dy-y1, dx-x1);//calculate angle
    velocity = new Vector2();
    velocity.x =  (float)(Math.cos(r) * SPEED);
    velocity.y = (float)(Math.sin(r) * SPEED) + ACCOUNT FOR GRAVITY;

    acceleration= new Vector2(0, GRAVITY);
}
```

and this is the update method, pretty straight forward

```
public void update(float delta)
{
    velocity.add(acceleration.cpy().scl(delta));
    position.add(velocity.cpy().scl(delta));
}
```

How do I account for gravity? If gravity is set to 0 the arrow travels in a straight line to the coordinates the mouse clicked, but with gravity it always falls short. Im not sure how to account for gravity. I think delta might be screwing me up.

Comment: Few notes:
1) if your SPEED is less than GRAVITY than your arrow will be falling like a stone   
2) your `velocity.y` component should be adjusted for gravity periodically (on every update/repaint)

Comment: so the "ACCOUNT FOR GRAVITY" should be moved to the update method. How would I calculate this though?

Comment: Gravity is a force that acts continuously decreasing vertical speed by (close to) 10m/s every second (on Earth). So for crude calculation it is enough to decrement vertical (Y) component of speed by acceleration every second.

Answer (score 2):

This is more of a math / physics question than a programming question. So first of all, you know the horizontal velocity of the arrow is constant (unless you have air resistance, in which case it is a lot more complicated). You can calculate the time it will take for the arrow to reach it's destination's x coordinate.

```
let (dx, dy) = displacement from launcher to destination
let c = cos(angle), s = sin(angle), vx = c * speed, vy = s * speed

vx * t = dx
t = dx / vx
```

With this value, you can compute the vertical displacement

```
dy = 0.5*acc * t^2 + V0 * t
dy = 0.5*acc * (dx/vx)^2 + vy*t

dy = 0.5*acc * (dx/(c*speed))^2 + (s*speed)*(dx/(c*speed))
```

since sin = sqrt(1 - cosine^2),

```
dy = 0.5*acc * (dx/(c*speed))^2 + (sqrt(1-c^2)*speed)*(dx/c*speed))
```

Now you have an equation with only known values (acc, dy, dx, speed) and c. If you solve for c, you know the cosine and you can find the sin.

Comment: Sorry its been awhile since I took physics, but which variable would the "ACCOUNT FOR GRAVITY" end up being because from what I see all these variables can easily be solved for as I have the angle Math.atan2(dy-y1, dx-x1); Which I can use to get c and s. Or are you referring to the c and s in a different context? Thank you so much for helping.

Comment: @Korb This solution will allow you to find c and s given the location of the target, since "accounting for gravity" means finding the correct angle at which to launch the projectile.

Comment: Ahh okay, I understand now, that's perfect, but I'm having some problems isolating c, it's much harder than I thought, so far I have 
    dy * c^2 - sqrt(1-c^2) * dx * c = (0.5*a * dx^2)/speed^2
help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: @Korb I'm not sure you can solve it algebraically, you might have to use another method. I would post a question to the math stack exchange asking specifically how you would solve that equation. It may involve calculus.

Comment: I found a website that allowed me to solve it, I just had to split each variable name into one letter, if this doesnt look right let me know. This could be beneficial to you in the future too. [link](http://tinyurl.com/nzqdkuc)

Comment: This formula works perfectly accept that the s is always positive, but I was able to calculate when it should be made negative so it now works perfectly, thanks for all the help